# Databricks Github action Authorization failed

Tags: github-actions, databricks, databricks-cli

My Databricks Github action suddenly stopped working. It was working fine one day, then the next it started failing. I keep on getting the error `Error: Authorization failed. Your token may be expired or lack the valid scope`
Any ideas as to why this is happening? this action is just updating my databricks repo

Github action:

```
name: "Update Databricks PROD repo"

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:  
  sync_job:    
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest   
    name: Job to sync Databricks PROD repo when releasing        
    steps:
      - name: update databricks prod repo          
        run: |          
          echo "updating databricks repo: prod"         
          python -m pip install --upgrade databricks-cli
          cat > ~/.databrickscfg << EOF
          [DEFAULT]
          host = ${{ vars.DATABRICKS_HOST }}
          token = ${{ secrets.DATABRICKS_TOKEN }}
          jobs-api-version = 2.1 
          EOF
          databricks repos update --path /Repos/prod/mindset_etl --branch main
```

action job log:

```
echo "updating databricks repo: prod"         
  python -m pip install --upgrade databricks-cli
  cat > ~/.databrickscfg << EOF
  [DEFAULT]
  host = https://adb-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.2.azuredatabricks.net/?o=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  token = ***
  jobs-api-version = 2.1 
  EOF
  databricks repos update --path /Repos/prod/mindset_etl --branch main
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
updating databricks repo: prod
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting databricks-cli
  Downloading databricks_cli-0.18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (150 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 150.3/150.3 KB 3.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting urllib3<3,>=1.26.7
  Downloading urllib3-2.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (121 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 121.1/121.1 KB 13.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: click>=7.0 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from databricks-cli) (8.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: oauthlib>=3.1.0 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from databricks-cli) (3.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyjwt>=1.7.0 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from databricks-cli) (2.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.17.3 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from databricks-cli) (2.25.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from databricks-cli) (1.16.0)
Collecting tabulate>=0.7.7
  Downloading tabulate-0.9.0-py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
Installing collected packages: urllib3, tabulate, databricks-cli
Successfully installed databricks-cli-0.18.0 tabulate-0.9.0 urllib3-2.2.1
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py:87: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (2.2.1) or chardet (4.0.0) doesn't match a supported version!
  warnings.warn("urllib3 ({}) or chardet ({}) doesn't match a supported "
Error: Authorization failed. Your token may be expired or lack the valid scope
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. Someone on the team enabled IP allow list in github for the repos. I had to add the Databricks IP `20.42.4.210` to the list.